# Migrate from file-loader with postTransformPublicPath to Asset Modules

Tags: webpack, cdn, webpack-5, webpack-file-loader

I want to migrate [file-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader) to [asset modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/). `file-loader` is deprecated.

I use this feature for CDN.

```
postTransformPublicPath: (p) => `__webpack_public_path__ + ${p}`,
```

But I can't find on-the-fly rewrite with `__webpack_public_path__` on new asset modules.
Do you have any solutions for that?

related:
[Webpack 5 - Asset Module - Missing feature of url-loader - postTransformPublicPath - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031444/webpack-5-asset-module-missing-feature-of-url-loader-posttransformpublicpa)